# Laravel can't find a class from my library

Tags: php, laravel, azure, class, oauth

I'm trying to add oauth2 azure authentification to my laravel project. I found this library : [text](https://github.com/hdvinhhoang/laravel-oauth2-azure) and i've followed all the steps on the git. But this not work. When i redirect to azure in my controller it make an error when register function is load in AzureServiceProvider.php. Laravel could not find class \VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure in the bind function.

My login controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Lang;
use Azure;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    public function showLoginForm() {
      if (Auth::Check())
      {
        return redirect('/');
      }
      return Azure::redirect();
    }
}
```

AzureServiceProvider.php :

```
namespace VinhHoang\OAuth2;

use App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AzureServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/Config/oauth2azure.php' => config_path('oauth2azure.php')
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('azure', function () {
            return new \VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure;
        });
    }
}
```

Azure.php :

```
namespace VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\AbstractGrant;
use VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Grant\JwtBearer;
use VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class Azure extends AbstractProvider
{
    use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

    public $urlLogin = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    public $pathAuthorize = "/oauth2/authorize";
    public $pathToken = "/oauth2/token";

    public $scope = [];

    public $tenant = "";

    public $urlAPI = "https://graph.windows.net/";
    public $resource = "";

    public $API_VERSION = "1.6";

    public $authWithResource = true;

    public function __construct(array $collaborators = [])
    {
        //load config
        $config = config('oauth2azure');
        $this->tenant = $config['tenant'];

        parent::__construct($config, $collaborators);
        $this->grantFactory->setGrant('jwt_bearer', new JwtBearer);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user of the application to the provider's authentication screen.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function redirect()
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->getAuthorizationUrl());
    }

 ...
```

Laravel Framework 6.20.44
PHP 7.4.33

What I've already tried :

- composer update
- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan optimize
- In composer.json,  "vinhhoang/oauth2-azure": "^1.0", is present

But all of this change nothing and the namespace are good i think. Lower and Uppercase in namespace are good too.

Any other idea for why when register function is load in AzureServiceProvider.php, Laravel could not find class \VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure in the bind function. ?

PS :
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Do you have setting Service Provider and Facade in file `config/app.php` ?

Comment: @Doelmi Yes. 'providers' => [VinhHoang\OAuth2\AzureServiceProvider::class,] and 'aliases' => [ 'Azure' =>  VinhHoang\OAuth2\Facades\Azure::class,]

Comment: is there any screenshot or error trace you can provide?

Comment: @Doelmi I just found this error when run composer dump-autoload : Class VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure located in ./vendor/vinhhoang/oauth2-azure/src/Provider/Azure.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping. But is it a good idea to modify in namespace in vendor ?

Comment: You should not change anything in vendor folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !! The namespace were wrong ! I have to change namespace from library, from : "VinhHoang\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure" to VinhHoang\OAuth2\Provider\Azure. Just removed "Client" from namespace. Do that foreach class in vinhhoang library.